# Check all possible AJAX responses

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an AJAX function which POST data to a PHP handler. I echo back either "success" or "failure" from PHP to determine if it was completed as intended. Unfortunately I am not used to JS/AJAX and have trouble finding documentation that answers my questions.

Do I need to JSON encode the response? I only check for .done() in my AJAX function, should I also check success and failed? My code inside of .done() which is just an alert box isn't working, despite the functionality in the PHP handler running without issue.

JS/AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function powerSignal(device, signal)
    {
        var cfm = confirm("Do you wish to ___ the server?");

        if (cfm==true)
        {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "https://domain.net/modules/power_functions.php", data: { device: device, 'power_signal': signal }}).done(function(result)
            {
                alert("success!");
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
if ( isset($_POST["device"]) && isset($_POST["power_signal"]) )
{
    $deviceid = $_POST["device"];
    $signal = $_POST["power_signal"];

    //API: Get Device Inventory
    $url = 'http://domain.net/dp/api/set_device_power_status';
    $fields = array('deviceid' => urlencode($deviceid), 'power_signal' => urlencode($signal));
    $result = curl_get($url, $fields);
    $json = json_decode($result);

    $status = $json->{'status'};

    if ($status == "success")
    {
        echo "success";
    }

    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use JSON if the response is just a string. That's needed when you're returning structured data, like an array.

Comment: BTW, `$json->{'status'}` is usually written as `$json->status`. You only need `{}` when the property name is computed.

Comment: @Barmar: That is what I thought but I wasn't sure. I looked at some of my other working code and only encoded array data, but as the AJAX callback isn't working I figured I would ask.

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what's being returned by the AJAX?

Comment: Ah, it seems Developer Tools is reporting "TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function". Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: If your jQuery is too old, you need to use the `success:` option to `$.ajax` rather than the `.done` method.

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function" as well. This is actually a PHP Module that is loaded into other software (WHMCS Billing System) so I assumed JQuery was already loaded when the module was ran. I just tried adding JQuery 1.11.0 but no change. As these are PHP Modules and I am basically inserting the JQuery script src and JS code in the middle of it, could that be an issue?

Comment: `success:` is an OPTION, not a METHOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the content of the `result` variable will be what the server sends back, you'll have to test it :

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "https://domain.net/modules/power_functions.php", data: { device: device, 'power_signal': signal }}).done(function(result)
            {
                if(result=='success'){
                    alert("success!");
                }else{
                    alert("failure!");
            });
```

To answer the comment below, here is how I do in my current project with a simple get request :

```
            $.get( "/getResult/"+data, function( results ) {
                $('.popin_content').html('<p>Vos documents ont bien été créés :</p><br/><ul><li><a href="/getPDF/'+results+'">Plan PDF</a></li><li>Devis PDF</li></ul>');


            });
```

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear on that. The alert() is just a test, which isn't being ran. The PHP function is running successfully, the callback just doesn't seem to be called as no alert is displayed.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I've edited my answer with a working ajax query using JQuery.

Comment: What is the HTTP status being returned from the server? I believe the `done` callback in jQuery only gets invoked if a 200 or 201 status is returned. If a non 20x HTTP status is returned, use the `fail` callback in jQuery to process that case.